# Tactic Installation on centos 7

Tags: tactic

I am doing installation of [tactic](http://community.southpawtech.com/tactic/community/link/get_started) 4.5 on centos 7.

i am following
http://community.southpawtech.com/tactic-sys-admin_sys-admin_install-tactic-centos-6.2.html

but in the end when i am trying to access tactic through web
i am getting this error:

```
The requested URL /tactic was not found on this server.
```

Comment: what is the status of apache and postgres ..?

Comment: systemctl status httpd.service   and  systemctl status postgresql-9.6.service

Comment: both services are Active: active (running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure apache properly to fix this.

1. Copy tactic configuration file in /etc/httpd/conf.d folder

`cp /opt/tactic/tactic_data/config/tactic.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d`

2. open httpd.conf file and add `Include conf.d/*.conf`  in the end
3. `systemctl restart httpd.service`